# Javascript textbox getting focus but keypad not populated in ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, forms

I have created popup with form which is working fine , but what I need is to auto populate keypad by focusing first form field in the popup when user open popup to fill form.

I have tried below all possibilities

```
 document.getElementById("name").focus();

 document.getElementById("name").click();

 $('#name').click().focus();

 setTimeout(function(){
    document.getElementById("name").focus();
 },200);
```

which is focusing but keyboard not populating in IOS Devices.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's not as easy as I thought before.

```
var focus = function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    var clone = input.cloneNode(true);
    var parent = input.parentElement;
    parent.appendChild(clone);
    parent.replaceChild(clone, input);
    input = clone;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        input.value = input.value || "";
        input.focus();
    }, 0);
}
```

reference: [How to Open Keyboard on iOS with JS](http://4pcbr.com/topic/how_to_open_keyboard_on_ipad_with_js)

Comment: @GrandhiManikanta I don't know what's wrong... You should check out the article I listed. The author did it.